# parsing a JSON string response. Already tried JSON.parse()

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, object

I have a response object that looks something like this -

```
{  
location: '{country:Poland,latitude:50.0575,longitude:19.9802}',
ip: '83.26.234.177',
name: 'John Doe'   
}
```

I am trying to read the country name like this -

```
data.forEach(function(datapoint) {
    dataObject.ip = datapoint.ip;
    var locationObject = datapoint.location; // also tried JSON.parse
    console.log(locationObject); //{country:Poland,latitude:50.0575,longitude:19.9802}
    console.log(locationObject.country); // undefined
    console.log(locationObject.latitude); //undefined
    console.log(locationObject.longitude); //undefined
}
```

getting `undefined`.

Comment: Your location property is string.

Comment: Where is it getting undefined?

Comment: Yeah don't think that is valid json

Comment: `location` value is not a valid JSON string, the valid JSON string is `{"country":"Poland","latitude":50.0575,"longitude":19.9802}`

Comment: Edited to show the undefined values

Comment: `datapoint.location` is a string.  It doesn't have any properties.

Comment: Fix the server that is giving you an invalid response. File a bug report if it isn't yours.

Comment: Fixed the backend. Getting a correct response now which is a valid JSON -
{"country":"Poland","latitude":51.9667,"longitude":19.7333}. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`datapoint.location` is a not valid json. Use [String#replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to convert it to a valid json string and then parse:

```js
var data = [{
  location: '{country:Poland,latitude:50.0575,longitude:19.9802}',
  ip: '83.26.234.177',
  name: 'John Doe'
}];


data.forEach(function(datapoint) {
  var json = datapoint.location.replace(/([^\d\.{}:,]+)/g, '"$1"'); // wrap the keys and non number values in quotes
  var locationObject = JSON.parse(json);
  console.log(locationObject.country);
  console.log(locationObject.latitude);
  console.log(locationObject.longitude);
});
```

Comment: Fixed the backend. Getting a correct response now which is a valid JSON -
{"country":"Poland","latitude":51.9667,"longitude":19.7333}. Thanks for the suggestion. That also would help if the backend sends incorrect response and u have no control over it

Comment: Fixing the problem at the source is indeed the better option. I've assumed you can't :)

Comment: In this case it will.

Answer (score 1):

The value inside of your `location` property is not valid JSON. `JSON.parse` fails because of that. You would need the following:

```
'{"country":"Poland","latitude":50.0575,"longitude":19.9802}'
```

Note how the properties and string values are surrounded with `"`s.